# Difference between Socket recv, sysread and Posix::read in sockets?

Tags: perl

I find at least 3 ways to read from a nonblocking socket in perl

```
$socket->recv
$socket->sysread
POSIX::read($socket,...
```

looks like 3 different names to the same thing, I read the documentations but I can't find one huge differente. anyone?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sysread` is stream (TCP) oriented (it doesn't care about where one send ends and another begins), and `recv` is datagram (UDP) oriented (it does care).

`POSIX::read` works on file descriptors, whereas `sysread` works on file handles.

Comment: Correction: `recv` actually works fine with streams too. It might even be a better choice than `sysread`. `recv` is simply specific to sockets, while `sysread` works with all streams (e.g. it also works with plain files).

Comment: See also: [What is the difference between `read` and `sysread`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36315124/589924) (Note that this is about the builtin `read`.  `POSIX::read` is closer to `sysread`.)

Answer (score 2):

The best source for documentation on `recv()` is `man recvfrom` - it is basically a perl interface to that system call. Note that `recv()` is usually used on sockets which are set up non-connection oriented (i.e. a UDP socket), but it may be also be used on connection oriented (i.e. TCP) sockets.

The man differences between `read()`, `sysread()` and `POSIX::read()` are:

- `read(...)` takes a file handle and the IO is buffered
- `sysread(...)` takes a file handle and the IO is not buffered
- `POSIX::read(...)` takes a file descriptor and the IO is not buffered

A file descriptor is a value (a small integer) that is returned by `POSIX::open()`.
Also, you can get the file descriptor of a perl file handle via the `fileno()` function.