# What is the difference between `read` and `sysread`?

Tags: perl, io, system-calls

[`read`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/read.html) and [`sysread`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysread.html) have very similar documentation. What are the differences between the two?

Comment: grrr :-) that's a good question

Comment: Credit to @G. Cito for prompting this question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

About [`read`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/read.html):

- `read` supports PerlIO layers.
- `read` works with any Perl file handle<sup>[1]</sup>.
- `read` buffers.
- `read` obtains data from the system in fixed sized blocks of 8 KiB<sup>[2]</sup>.
- `read` may block if less data than requested is available<sup>[3]</sup>.

About [`sysread`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysread.html):

- `sysread` doesn't support PerlIO layers (meaning it requires a raw a.k.a. binary handle).
- `sysread` only works with Perl file handles that map to a system file handle/descriptor<sup>[4]</sup>.
- `sysread` doesn't buffer.
- `sysread` performs a single system call.
- `sysread` returns immediately if data is available to be returned, even if the amount of data is less than the amount requested.

Summary and conclusions:

- `read` works with any Perl file handle, while `sysread` is limited to Perl file handles mapped to a system file handle/descriptor.
- `read` isn't compatible with [`select`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html)<sup>[5]</sup>, while `sysread` is compatible with `select`.
- `read` can perform decoding for you, while `sysread` requires that you do your own decoding.
- `read` should be faster for very small reads, while `sysread` should be faster for very large reads.

---

Notes:

1. These include, for example, tied file handles and those created using `open(my $fh, '<', \$var)`.
2. Before 5.14, Perl read in 4 KiB blocks. Since 5.14, the size of the blocks is configurable when you build `perl`, with a default of 8 KiB.
3. In my experience, `read` will return exactly the amount requested (if possible) when reading from a plain file, but may return less when reading from a pipe. These results are by no means guaranteed.
4. [`fileno`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fileno.html) returns a non-negative number for these. These include, for example, handles that read from plain files, from pipes and from sockets, but not those mentioned in [1].
5. I'm referring to the 4-argument one called by [IO::Select](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO::Select).

Comment: Great summary. - should be in perlfunc. This: "`read` should be faster for small reads, while `sysread` should be faster for large reads." is exactly what is needed. Of course, given the infinite possibilities of the real word, it may not **always** be true but a mostly truthy perlish guideline is what I want.

Comment: In a response to [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36208336/2019415) I used [`Stream::Reader`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Stream::Reader). As an experiment I replaced `read` with `sysread` in `Reader.pm` and gained 9-10% throughput - it seemed too easy.  Besides the obvious bits (buffering, encoding,) is it just a question of benchmarking and testing?  Can you speak to any data integrity, failover/robustness elements of this?

Comment: @G.Cito in reusable code such as Stream::Reader, you have to assume filehandles may have layers, so sysread is not an option.

Comment: @G. Cito, Talk of "UTF-8 mode" implies it's not just a possibility that they have layers, but that it's a supported mode of operation. That prevents `sysread` from being a valid option.

Comment: Also, you can `read` from things that aren't actually files (perhaps you opened a filehandle to a scalarref or `TIEHANDLE`d something), but you can only `sysread` something with a positive `fileno()`.

Comment: @ikegami: How about `write` and `syswrite`?

Comment: @cuonglm, They're not even similar. I think you mean `print` and `syswrite`. Of the two, I've only ever used `print` because it's easier to use. I don't know if there are any other differences.